# Understanding GML structure for validation

Tags: geotools, xml, gml

I'm failing to convert this GML v3.2 XML and I'm not sure why:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gml:MultiGeometry xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="">
   <gml:geometryMember>
      <gml:Envelope srsDimension="2" srsName="EPSG:4326">
         <gml:lowerCorner>-67.4608695652174 -23.6347826086957</gml:lowerCorner>
         <gml:upperCorner>-32.0869565217391 -1.40869565217392</gml:upperCorner>
      </gml:Envelope>
   </gml:geometryMember>
</gml:MultiGeometry>
```

How is this supposed to be structured? I assume the envelope cannot be nested under the member tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt the best place to look is the [GML schema](http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/) (though I prefer one of the [annotated sites](http://www.wmo.int/schemas/wmdr/1.0RC4/documentation/schemadoc/schemas/geometryBasic0d1d_xsd/complexTypes/AbstractGeometryType.html)).

So [`gml:geometryMember`](http://www.wmo.int/schemas/wmdr/1.0RC4/documentation/schemadoc/schemas/geometryAggregates_xsd/elements/geometryMember.html) can contain a [`gml:AbstractGeometry`](http://www.wmo.int/schemas/wmdr/1.0RC4/documentation/schemadoc/schemas/geometryBasic0d1d_xsd/complexTypes/AbstractGeometryType.html) which can be one of the 29 geometry types (`gml:AbstractCurve`, `gml:AbstractGeometricAggregate`, `gml:AbstractGeometricPrimitive`, `gml:AbstractGeometry`, `gml:AbstractImplicitGeometry`, `gml:AbstractSolid`, `gml:AbstractSurface`, `gml:CompositeCurve`, `gml:CompositeSolid`, `gml:CompositeSurface`, `gml:Curve`, `gml:GeometricComplex`, `gml:Grid`, `gml:LineString`, `gml:MultiCurve`, `gml:MultiGeometry`, `gml:MultiPoint`, `gml:MultiSolid`, `gml:MultiSurface`, `gml:OrientableCurve`, `gml:OrientableSurface`, `gml:Point`, `gml:Polygon`, `gml:PolyhedralSurface`, `gml:RectifiedGrid`, `gml:Solid`, `gml:Surface`, `gml:Tin`, `gml:TriangulatedSurface`) but not [`gml:Envelope`](http://www.wmo.int/schemas/wmdr/1.0RC4/documentation/schemadoc/schemas/geometryBasic0d1d_xsd/elements/Envelope.html).

A [`gml:Envelope`](http://www.wmo.int/schemas/wmdr/1.0RC4/documentation/schemadoc/schemas/geometryBasic0d1d_xsd/elements/Envelope.html) is a [`gml:EnvelopeType`](http://www.wmo.int/schemas/wmdr/1.0RC4/documentation/schemadoc/schemas/geometryBasic0d1d_xsd/complexTypes/EnvelopeType.html) and is not considered a geometry.

So it would appear to be invalid GML.